# Java - Object value attributes

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am taking a Java EE Servlets course and had a question about what "object-value attributes" are? I have never heard that term before.

Answer (score 1):

**Object Value attributes** are nothing but, the attributes that are used in a POJO class.

```
public class Employee{
   private Integer employeeId;
   private String employeeName;

   //standard getters and setters
}
```

Here the `employeeId` and `employeeName` can be considered as object value attributes.

So now when we try to use any of the attributes from this:

```
Employee e = new Employee();
e.setEmployeeId(1234);
Integer objectValueAttribute = e.getEmployeeId();
```